# Timeout Exception in Zuul based routing

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, hystrix

I have got the below setup in which my Eureka server is running and few services created and registered with Eureka are running. All the service to service calls are happing using rest template which has been load balanced and every thing is working fine.

Now, I have introduced the Zuul based routing to the application with below code/properties -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
     public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
         final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource= new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
         final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
         corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
         corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("*");
         corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");
         corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
         corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
         corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("GET");
         corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
         corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("POST");
         corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
         corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
         urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
         return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
     }
}
```

With this my routing is working absolutely fine, however now there is a service which takes close to 12 seconds in its execution and my business requirements prohibit to break into smaller calls.

This results in Timeout exception in Zuul.

Below is my .yml file -

```
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 60000
  ReadTimeout: 600000
zuul:
  host:
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
                timeout:
                    enabled: false
```

Somehow the ZuulException is still coming and i am completely failing to understand what else i can do in this.

The service i am calling from Zuul API gateway has in its main class -

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
```

and in the service -

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "addUserFallback")
public String addUser(....
```

Also the fall back method

```
public String addUserFallback(...
```

Error stack -

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: irusermanager timed-out and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:805) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:790) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1470) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1395) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:44) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:28) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:142) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:1121) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:1138) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleTimeoutViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:980) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$500(AbstractCommand.java:59) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:595) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:587) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? What kind of result is expected?

Comment: I am getting "exception":"com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException","message":"TIMEOUT" and i expect my API to return the actual output which is some data. However it seems zuul + hystrix + ribbon is timing out my request which generally takes around 12 seconds

Comment: Have you tried: **hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000** ?

Comment: Yes bart, i tried that option as well, but same result.

Comment: edited original question a bit to showcase what i am doing at the actual service layer.

Comment: Could you paste whole stack trace?

Comment: Edited the original question with stack

Comment: Dont know if this will help but i have changed my service method to below -

Comment: @HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {
         @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "60000")},
   fallbackMethod = "addUserFallback")
 public String addUser(RegisterInputDTO user) {

Comment: The timeout should be set in zuul, where the exception is thrown, i think

Comment: i have done that in the .yml file of zuul as well, does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that the request comes to service? Is there any sign of it?

Comment: Yes, logs are printed of my service and then as soon as 5s time is hit request times out

Comment: Try setting hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy: THREAD in zuul properties, and tell me if it worked

Comment: Bart, i dont know but something weired happening now. Zuul is still returning exception after 5 seconds but my services log says that the complete service of 22 seconds actually ran

Comment: I have one more idea: zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis: 60000

Comment: Already added in my Zuul yml file.

Comment: Hi I am stuck with similar issue. What was the solution you implemented for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
zuul:
  host:
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
    connect-timeout-millis: 60000 #important

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true  #important
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  ConnectTimeout: 60000

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000 #important
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the properties and dependencies name/Id has been changed. 
Please try the below properties.

```
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 60000 //60 sec
  ReadTimeout: 60000 //60 sec
```

I hope this will help you to resolve an issue with the Zuul API Gateway Timeout error.