# Jhipster Timeout Exception getting swagger api-docs

Tags: spring, jhipster, netflix-zuul, hystrix

We have developed a microservice environment using JHIPSTER. Since we changed the display URLs of the swagger api-docs we encountered timeouts when trying to retrieve the json.

The deployment is done with docker swarm, and the exception stack is:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:88)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at com.queres.smartgov.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:207)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: sd_api timed-out and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:805)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:790)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1451)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1376)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:44)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:28)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:1121)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:1138)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleTimeoutViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:980)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$500(AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:595)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:587)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

We have the following timeout settings in the gateway:

```
zuul:
    host:
        connect-timeout-millis: 60000
        socket-timeout-millis: 60000

# See https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration
hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
                isolation:
                    thread:
                        timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

The point is that timeouts sometimes doesn't happen if I redeploy services.

The problem is similar to this one (unsolved): [Timeout Exception in Zuul based routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792061/timeout-exception-in-zuul-based-routing)

**UPDATE**

Url in GW: http://localhost:8080/#/docs

We change the deploy url of swagger json in the microservices. For example we change from http://localhost:8080/sd_api/v2/api-docs to http://localhost:8080/sd_api/1.0/api-docs

I found something strange. The microservice that returns the timeout has an strange IP in discovery service (10.255.0.4). But if I execute a ping in GW containter to service name, it resolves it as: 10.0.0.2

Comment: Please provide details about the URL you access on gateway and what you did change in JHipster code to make it somehow work. Clarify also what you mean by "we changed the display URLs of the swagger api-docs".

Comment: I update the info. Thanks!

Comment: I think that will be something about the wrong IP in discoveryService